# How do I define an int32_t * cdata pointer in Python?

Tags: python, pointers, ctypes, ffi, cdata

suppose I have the following code in Python:

```
from cffi import FFI
ffi = FFI()
ffi.cdef("""
int32_t function(char** ct, int32_t *ct_len);

ct = ffi.new("char **")
```

How do I define `ct_len`?

Answer (score 0):

An `int32_t *` could conventionally be two things in C:

- Just a pointer to a single `int32_t`
- A pointer to an array of `int32_t`s

Which one it is, and hence how to declare it in Python cffi syntax thus depends on the function itself and how it's documented.

Comment: In this case it should be the length of the first param, so a single `int32_t`